# How to install cudnn.torch?

Tags: lua, torch

[Their page](https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch/tree/R4) contains `Installation` section but it is not understandable by one, who does not know torch and lua (like me): section enumerates prerequisites installtion, but has no word about `cudnn.torch` itself.

Repository contains bunch of `lua` files. What to do with them to "install"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install cuda first (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads), then download the cudnn bindings (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads).

Then if you have already installed torch, `luarocks install cudnn` should be enough.

For a full installation, you can have a look at [this tuto](https://github.com/fonfonx/Tutorials/blob/master/Cutorch/nvidia.md).

Comment: `luarocks` is like `pip` in `python`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install from the github repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch
cd cudnn.torch
luarocks make
```

Depending on your installed version of CUDA you may need to specify a specific branch of the repo, e.g. `git clone https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch.git -b R7`